# IntelliJ Can't start Git after updating to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea, windows-8.1

So I recently went through to pain of updating to Windows 8.1 from 8, but now I'm having issues with IntelliJ and Git.

When starting IntelliJ I receive an error stating:

```
Can't start Git: C:\cygwin\bin\git.exe
     Probably the path to Git executable is not valid. Fix it.
```

Pressing "Fix  it." takes me to the Git settings within version control and the correct path is displayed, pressing Test shows the following message:

```
Git executed successfully Git version is 1.7.9.0
```

Attempting any form of Git command fails quietly, which leaves me unable to pull, push etc.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Running IntelliJ in XP SP3 Compatability mode seems to be a work around, I've logged a bug with JetBrains for the time being.